# When we have to call a block in phtml as getBlockHtml('') or getChildHtml('')?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, magento-1, xml

In this case I suppose that I can call this block in a phtml as `getBlockHtml('my.name')` right !

To call it as `getChilHtml('my.name')` what do I have to do in a xml ?

```
<my_handle_layout>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.name" template="page/custom/my-template.phtml" />
    </reference>
<my_handle_layout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`getChildHtml` can be used to retrieve a child block HTML.**

Example.

```
<my_handle_layout>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.name" template="page/custom/my-template.phtml">
            <block type="core/template" name="my.child" template="my/template.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
<my_handle_layout>
```

In that case in your `page/custom/my-template.phtml` template (your `my.name` block) you can call `echo $this->getChildHtml('my.child');` to get the HTML of your child `my.child`

**`getBlockHtml` can be used to retrieve a block HTML, understand any block.**

An easy to understand example from the core is the form key block declared like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <block name="formkey" type="core/template" template="core/formkey.phtml" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

As you can see it's just a block assigned to every page.

In any template you can call `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>` to display that block

**Clarification regarding your question**

In your case, you've assigned the block to the `content` structural block declared in the `page.xml` layout file:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```

As this is a structural block (of type `core/text_list`) you don't need to do anything to get your custom block rendered because **structural blocks render all their child automatically**

Comment: Thank Raphael for your reply, however i want to know something, in the xml declaration we can declare all type block as "core/template" in all cases because all blocks types inherits core/tempate right ? when i can check this in the code

Comment: @Prince most of the time it's `core/template` but you can also declare structural blocks (`core/text_list`) or simple text block (`core/text`)

Comment: Thanks, are you from france ?

Comment: @Prince yes I am

Comment: @Prince feel free to contact me on Twitter (see the link on my profile). If you need to endorse me, you can use CommerceHero: https://commercehero.io/raphaelpetrini